# Sorting arrays syntax in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting, element

This is a very basic question but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding Rubys hash sort method.

Basically whats happening is I'm receiving a cannot convert string to integer so my first guess is I'm sorting the array by a string (which is actually a number). The array contains hashes and I'm trying to sort it by one of the hashes values that I've identified with a key.

Heres how I'm sorting my array:

```
@receivedArray =(params[:respElementDatas])

    puts @receivedArray.class #Its definitely an array
    @sortedArray = @receivedArray.sort_by{|ed| ed["element_type_id"]}
```

The error I'm getting is can't convert String into Integer on the sort line.

Naturally I assumed that

Just a quick question.
Am i right in saying that 'ed' is an object that is stored in the array and I'm referencing it correctly? Also any pointers on how to fix it?

Comment: what does `puts @receivedArray.inspect` give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@receivedArray` is an array of arrays or has at least one array in it. For example:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
a.sort_by { |e| e['x'] }
# TypeError: can't convert String into Integer

a = [{:a => :a},{:b => :b},[1,2,3]]
[{:a=>:a}, {:b=>:b}, [1, 2, 3]]
a.sort_by { |e| e['x'] }
# TypeError: can't convert String into Integer

a = [{'where' => 'is'},{'pancakes' => 'house'}]
[{"where"=>"is"}, {"pancakes"=>"house"}]
a.sort_by { |e| e['x'] }
# No error this time
```

Answer (score 0):

try `ed["element_type_id"].to_i`

Answer (score 0):

You are right in saying that 'ed' is an object that is stored in the array.
If all the elements in the array are hashes then you are referencing it correctly?

Some of the hashes have a String and others have an Integer for the element_type_id.

I'd check where you are mixing the data for the element_type_id.

You could try `ed["element_type_id"].to_i` which for an integer will have no effect, but for a string will parse it into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error is saying that `ed` is an `Array`, not a `Hash`.  It may be an array of pairs:  `[['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']]`, in which case you would want to change your code to:

```
@sortedArray = @receivedArray.sort_by{ |ed| ed.assoc("element_type_id") }
```

As rubyprince suggested, seeing the output of `p @receivedArray` would help clarify this.